# Модернизация обычной загрузки изображений в многозагрузочную

Tags: php, sql, веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста как этот скрип преобразовать что бы можно было грузить несколько фото.
Я думал добавить в базе еще несколько столбцов туда грузить картинки. Но пока не знаю будет это работать. И думаю есть что то получше.
Так же если нет возможности писать тут прошу дать ответ на почту drakxel@bk.ru.

Форма:

```
Размер изображения не превышает 512 Кб, пиксели по ширине не более 500, по высоте не более 1500.
<form class="form__control"  action="uploads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Выберите файл для загрузки:
 <input  type="file" name="files" ><br>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

Обработчик:

```
<?php
    require "../includes/config.php";
?>
<?php
$article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM `articles` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
                                                     $art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($article);

// подключаемся к серверу

$uploaddir = '../static/images/';
// это папка, в которую будет загружаться картинка

$apend=date('YmdHis').rand(100,1000).'.jpg'; 

// это имя, которое будет присвоенно изображению 
$uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend"; 
//в переменную $uploadfile будет входить папка и имя изображения

// В данной строке самое важное - проверяем загружается ли изображение (а может вредоносный код?)
// И проходит ли изображение по весу. В нашем случае до 512 Кб
if(($_FILES['files']['type'] == 'image/gif' || $_FILES['files']['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $_FILES['files']['type'] == 'image/png') && ($_FILES['files']['size'] != 0 and $_FILES['files']['size']<=512000)) 
{ 
// Указываем максимальный вес загружаемого файла. Сейчас до 512 Кб 
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
   { 
   //Здесь идет процесс загрузки изображения 
   $size = getimagesize($uploadfile); 
   // с помощью этой функции мы можем получить размер пикселей изображения 
     if ($size[0] < 501 && $size[1]<1501) 
     { 
     // если размер изображения не более 500 пикселей по ширине и не более 1500 по  высоте 
     echo "Файл загружен. Путь к файлу: <b>".$uploadfile."</b>"; 

     } else {
     echo "Загружаемое изображение превышает допустимые нормы (ширина не более - 500; высота не более 1500)"; 
     unlink($uploadfile); 
     // удаление файла 
     } 
   } else {
   echo "Файл не загружен, вернитеcь и попробуйте еще раз";
   } 
} else { 
echo "Размер файла не должен превышать 512Кб";
} 
$link =  mysqli_connect(
  $config['db']['server'],
  $config['db']['username'],
  $config['db']['password'],
  $config['db']['name'])    or die("Ошибка1 " . mysqli_error($link));

                $query ="UPDATE `articles` SET `image`='".$apend."' WHERE `id`='".$art['id']."'";

                $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, идея ясна

html:

```
Размер изображения не превышает 512 Кб, пиксели по ширине не более 500, по высоте не более 1500.
<form class="form__control" action="uploads.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    Выберите файл для загрузки:
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple><br>
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Загрузить">
</form>
```

php:

```
<?php
require "../includes/config.php";

$article = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id FROM `articles` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
$art = mysqli_fetch_assoc($article);

// подключаемся к серверу

$uploaddir = '../static/images/';
// это папка, в которую будет загружаться картинка

$apend = date('YmdHis') . rand(100, 1000) . '.jpg';

// это имя, которое будет присвоенно изображению
$uploadfile = "$uploaddir$apend";
//в переменную $uploadfile будет входить папка и имя изображения
if (empty($_FILES['files'])) {
    print 'Не чего загружать';
    exit(0);
}

foreach ($_FILES['files'] as $file) {

// В данной строке самое важное - проверяем загружается ли изображение (а может вредоносный код?)
// И проходит ли изображение по весу. В нашем случае до 512 Кб
    if (($file['type'] == 'image/gif' || $file['type'] == 'image/jpeg' || $file['type'] == 'image/png') && ($file['size'] != 0 and $file['size'] <= 512000)) {
// Указываем максимальный вес загружаемого файла. Сейчас до 512 Кб
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            //Здесь идет процесс загрузки изображения
            $size = getimagesize($uploadfile);
            // с помощью этой функции мы можем получить размер пикселей изображения
            if ($size[0] < 501 && $size[1] < 1501) {
                // если размер изображения не более 500 пикселей по ширине и не более 1500 по  высоте
                echo "Файл загружен. Путь к файлу: <b>" . $uploadfile . "</b>";

            } else {
                echo "Загружаемое изображение превышает допустимые нормы (ширина не более - 500; высота не более 1500)";
                unlink($uploadfile);
                // удаление файла
            }
        } else {
            echo "Файл не загружен, вернитеcь и попробуйте еще раз";
        }
    } else {
        echo "Размер файла не должен превышать 512Кб";
    }
}

$link = mysqli_connect($config['db']['server'], $config['db']['username'], $config['db']['password'],
    $config['db']['name']) or die("Ошибка1 " . mysqli_error($link));

$query = "UPDATE `articles` SET `image`='" . $apend . "' WHERE `id`='" . $art['id'] . "'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Ошибка " . mysqli_error($link));
```